# Inlining an implicitly declared out variable compiles but doesn't get Visual Studio support

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c#-6.0

Consider the following scenarios:

#### Works:

```
SemanticModel semanticModel;
document.TryGetSemanticModel(out semanticModel);
```

#### Doesn't work:

```
var semanticModel;
document.TryGetSemanticModel(out semanticModel);
```

#### Works:

```
document.TryGetSemanticModel(out SemanticModel semanticModel);
```

#### Works, BUT:

```
document.TryGetSemanticModel(out var semanticModel);
```

**But**: The code compiles, but there is no intellisense or documentation on hover. Is the last method considered syntactic sugar for the second one (which causes the below error) or does it more than just that?

> Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized

So am I looking at a bug in the implementation or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this will likely work once the C# 6 compiler is finished.  Right now, it does compile, but Roslyn is still a work in progress, and intellisense has limitations in the current build.

> So am I looking at a bug in the implementation or Visual Studio?

This is most likely a "bug" (really a feature that hasn't been implemented yet) in the compiler services used by Visual Studio.  I would recommend filing it as an [Issue in the Roslyn Codebase](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).